# WebGL lights number limitation

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

Context: I am playing with Three.js and some *PointLight* [here](http://cdpn.io/yGLKh).

After a quick search it seems like for WebGL and OpenGL there is only a small number of light sources allowed (at the same time). It sounds like it would be a common requirement for most of 3d scenes made. Like to show a long street with lamps along. Or like in this little scene linked above to have more than 10 cannons firing at the same time. Is the only solution using a deferred renderer (I don't know what I am talking about but this technique had been the answer from Google and that the demos about it look gorgeous).

Would the simplest solution be to create a fragment shader to compute a group 8 lights? And then use some kind of blend technique (again: 'totally starting on these subjects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice demo.

Except for performance considerations, the number of lights [should not be an issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/2477) with `WebGLRenderer`. ( Yes, if you have many lights, `WebGLDeferredRenderer` would be preferred. )

I would consider this a three.js bug. Note that you are generating console errors.

The problem is that your are instantiating a light and setting it's visibility to `false` prior to the first rendering. If you set each light's visibility to `true` at the start, the demo runs without errors.

three.js r.66.

EDIT: @gero3 has fixed this bug in the three.js r.67dev branch.

[image: Earth Demo with 200 pointlights]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Thanks for opening the issue also.

Answer (score 1):

WebGL and OpenGL ES 2.0 have no limits with lights. Three.js might. old OpenGL before shaders did. With shaders you write your own so put as many as you want up to the memory/resource limits of the hardware.

Deferred rendering can be faster for a larger number of lights. It's arguably too big a topic for stackoverflow. Maybe someone else is up to the task. The short version is that instead of computing the final color of a pixel like most shaders do the shader just stores a bunch of data (unlit-colors, normals, positions) into multiple textures. After which a different shader reads those textures and computes lighting. For various reasons that can end up being faster. with the limitation that it can't handle transparency.

[Here's a tutorial here for OpenGL that might be useful](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html). And there are a few three.js [examples](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgldeferred_pointlights.html) you could dissect

Note: Deferred rendering generally requires the [WEBGL_draw_buffers extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_draw_buffers/) to be performant.